# How do I specify checkstyle version when using gradle 0.9-rc-1 code-quality plugin?

Tags: java, build, checkstyle, gradle

I've been using maven2 for a while now, and I'm trying out gradle build tool at the moment.

One of the things I would like to do is to run checkstyle, but my current project is using checkstyle 4.4 with rules that don't seem to be compatible with the latest version of checkstyle which gradle code-quality plugin is using. Sure, I can and probably should move on to the newer version of checkstyle eventually, but is there a way to specify which version of checkstyle to use when I'm using code-quality plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548931/gradle-change-checkstyle-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible programmatically at the moment. But one of our next milestones will allow you to do that.

Comment: I'm simply going to take your word for it. I hope gradle gains more traction in wider community which in turn would give more momentum to gradle development. When I tried it out, it excited me with a good balance of convention and flexibility.

Comment: @HansDockter Is it possible now?