# Gradle change checkstyle version

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

Java Checkstyle plugin just updated to 6.0 version(java 8 support). Looks like gradle using older version. How i can upgrade gradle checkstyle plugin to newer version?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "6.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [`gradle-estilo-plugin`](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin)? It sets up the entire checkstyle configuration you need directly from a gradle config block. You can control the version from there too. Check out the README example for tips.